# How to add Users City as an attribute in Open ID token?

Tags: azure, openid

I have azure B2C account. I have created an openID connect and created an UserFlow and in that userflow I have marked city as an attribute in application claim and user attribute. But Still when I decode my JWT token I don't get city as an attribute. Please help me with the issue.

Comment: Where do you decode the token? in your application or a tool like http://www.jwt.io ?

Comment: In My Application. But also I tried decoding token in jwt.io but still i am not able to fetch any extra attribute from it.

Comment: Are you looking at the access or ID-token? perhaps include a copy of the token in question?

Comment: Checked Both Access and ID token, but in both any extra attribute I add in the flow is not there.

Comment: Many clients do make a extra requests to the userinfo endpoint to get additional data about the user. Because in many cases they want to keep the tokens small..  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/userinfo

Comment: How to make that extra request?

Comment: To do that request, it depends on what libraries you use or you can do it manually, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/userinfo